# Moving content within the art board in sketch

Tags: sketch-app, artboard, content

I am working in sketch. My question is, is it possible to hand selected certain parts of the board and move them up in unison withough disturbing the non selected area? basically i have a long artboard that is a web page...the middle of the art board the content has been removed so there is a gap in the middle. i need to select as a one the bottom part of the content and move it up to the upper part, thus killing the gap that was created by removing some content?

Answer (score 1):

You can group all items and then select the group to move them around.
Sometimes it's not convenient to group items you want to move together. In this case you can just select the items and move them together.

To do this there are 2 options:

1. Select the layers by holding command/control while selecting multiple layers and nudge them with the arrow keys or drag them around.
2. Select the objects on the artboard while holding command/control+shift and nudge or drag them around.

If you're selecting a large area with no unselected objects in between you can also click and drag with your mouse to select a bigger area of layers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can group all the components you want to move and then take them wherever you want.

https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/09-grouping/1-groups.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely select all the items then group them that way you can just select that folder / group and use the move tool.